# for-loop for filename that have a specific string or a specific extension

Tags: bash, for-loop

- On a for-loop how do you search for both a specific string or a filename extension?

I have files that have no extension but have the string "-DT-" in the filename, and other files that have the extension .fff. I want to process both types.

```
local dir imfiles

for imfiles in "$dir"**/*-DT-!(.jpg); do
   printf "File processed: ${imfiles}\n"
done
```

- How can I make the for-loop to not only look for files that have the string -DT- but also files that have an extension .fff?

The result would be the for-loop processing both types of files. I have tried using an array, but it didn't work. I have seen a lot of examples of for-loop but none approaching this specific scenario.

Comment: You can use (GNU) find with the regex search option or with multiple names `find . -type f -name "*.fff" -o -name "*-DT-*"`

Comment: Take a look at `help for` and `...` in its syntax to get a hint.

Comment: `*-DT-!(.jpg)` should be `*-DT-!(*.jpg)`.  Otherwise most files with `-DT-` in the name and a `.jpg` suffix (e.g. `ABC-DT-XYZ.jpg`) will be processed.  My tests picked this up immediately.  It's a good idea to test this thoroughly yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
shopt -s dotglob extglob nullglob globstar

for imfiles in "$dir"**/@(*-DT-!(*.jpg)|*.fff); do
   printf "File processed: ${imfiles}\n"
done
```

- See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for an explanation of `!(*.jpg)` and `@(*-DT-!(*.jpg)|*.fff)`.

Comment: Thank you again. This works perfectly. I should have figured it out though. I am glad we have a post with a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One idea using `find` to locate the desired files (assuming all files located under the same `$dir`):

```
while read -r imfiles 
do
    printf "File processed: ${imfiles}\n"
done < <(find "${dir}" -name "*-DT-*" -o -name "*.fff" 2>/dev/null)
```

If the files are under different directories then chain 2 `find` calls together, eg:

```
while read -r imfiles 
do
    printf "File processed: ${imfiles}\n"
done < <(find "${dir}" -name "*-DT-*" 2>/dev/null; find . -name "*.fff" 2>/dev/null)
```

**NOTE:** adjust the `find` command as needed, eg, do not search in sub-directories, look for files of specific size, etc.

Comment: I was using find earlier but was told by more experienced programmers to avoid using find in a for-loop. That's why I am staying away from it.

Comment: did these 'more experienced programmers' provide an explanation for not using `find`? or was it more an issue with its use with a `for` loop (as opposed to this answer's use of a `while` loop)?

Comment: Good point. It was an issue with the use with a for loop. I am going try one of the solution from another post. If this doesn't work I will definitely try yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the two groups don't overlap, you can specify one after the other:

```
for imfile in "$dir"/*-DT-!(*.*) "$dir"/*.fff ; do
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but the for-loop still doesn't pick up the .fff files.

Comment: @Robin: Prefix `*.fff` with `"$dir"/`?

Comment: Yes, I used "$dir"/*-DT-!(*.*) *.fff. However, the solution proposed on the post from pjh works totally fine.